# How to call a javascript function from flash on actionscript1.0

Tags: actionscript

```
on (press)
{
here I want to call a javascript function
}
on (rollOver)
{
gotoAndPlay("guizhou");
}
on (rollOver)
{
startDrag ("1guizhou", true);
}
on (rollOut)
{
gotoAndPlay("kongk");
}
```

How to call a javascript function in the press event ? in as3.0 there is mouseevent but in as1.0 ,I don't konw how do that? Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use getURL:

```
getURL("javascript:functionName()");
```

additional about this function can be found at:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as2/reference/flashlite/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118ccf9c47f-7fc9.html